# Applying overflow-x to a CSS grid-column element seems to apply overflow-y too

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

In the following fiddle, the layout consists of:

- a `.Header`
- a `.Container` with `display: grid;`.

The container has two children styled with `grid-column`.
The first column has an image as a child that is transformed and therefore overflows on the top side of the column and on top of the header.

I would have expected that setting the `overflow-x` property will only hide any extra content on the left of the column but it also crops the image that is overflowing on the y axis even though the `overflow-y` is still set to visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/dmnsgn/kuk4065d/

CSS:

```
.Header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.Container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.LeftColumn {
  grid-column: col-start 2 / span 4;
}


.LeftColumn img {
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}

.RightColumn {
  grid-column: col-start 6 / span 6;
}
```

JS:

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".ToggleButton");
const leftColumn = document.querySelector(".LeftColumn");
let hasBug = false;

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    hasBug = !hasBug;

  if (hasBug) {
    leftColumn.style["overflow-x"] = "hidden";
    leftColumn.style["overflow-y"] = "visible";
  } else {
    leftColumn.style["overflow-x"] = null;
    leftColumn.style["overflow-y"] = "visible";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an `overflow` bug. It's normal behavior.

You're dealing with two different containers: `.Header` and `.Container`.

You're applying the `overflow` properties to descendants of `.Container`.

- `overflow-x: hidden` works because it's being asked to work inside `.Container` (its own block formatting context).
- `overflow-y: visible` fails to do what you expect because it's being asked to work outside `.Container` (another block formatting context).

In other words, `overflow` properties work inside a block formatting context and, by trying to make the image in `.Container` overflow into `.Header`, you are trying to get these properties to work across different block formatting contexts.

Here's more on the `overflow` property:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

A logical alternative that comes to mind is absolute positioning. However, in this case, that results in the same problem:

By removing the image from the normal flow with `position: absolute` and making the `.Container` the bounding box (with `position: relative`), the image again gets clipped at the top border. It can't overlap the header.

It's really not clear what your overall goal is with your layout, so I won't try to provide a detailed solution, which could involve altering the HTML, which may not be an option.

Consider making the image a grid item and using grid properties for sizing and positioning it.

Also, there's a whole section in the spec about combining the `transform` and `overflow` properties. It may be useful to you:

- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-rendering

Comment: I am not trying to make the image appear "inside" the Header, but on top of it, from the Container.

Comment: Understood. Any `overflow` you apply will clip it at the `.Container` edge. You need another method.

Comment: I see, I was expecting that using a `translate3d` would create another layer on the GPU and therefore allow its painting to be independent from the `.Container` but I guess it is not the case.

The example with the image is really a reduced case of a dom node with a bigger hierarchy that requires `overflow-x` to be present.

I think the solution here will be to move the image in its own container in between `.Header` and `.Container` to handle its own flow/sizing.

Thanks